# Enable - SP Feature fails to find the configuration section in the web apps config

Tags: c#, sharepoint, powershell

I have a site for which i want to activate feature using powershell

When i run the following command :

```
enable-spfeature FEATURE NAME -url http://URL
```

it throws an error :value cannot be null parameter name section.

it basically fails to find the configuration section located under the web application configuration.If i create a file with name powershell.exe.config and place it under the 
powershell folder ,it works fine but i dont want to touch the system folder.

Is it possible to give powershell a path of config located int some other folder and ask it to use that while activating feature.

I have tried something like this but with no luck

```
$configpath = "C:\DevTools.exe.config"
 [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE",$configpath)
enable-spfeature Feature name -url http://url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lee Activating the feature from powershell expects the configuration to be under the hosting process which is powershell in this case.

The solution to my problem was to load the configuration at run time as shown below and using windows powershell instead of using sharepoint management shell :

```
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE",$configpath)   
add-type -path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Configuration.dll
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.PowerShell            
enable-spfeature $FeatureName -url http:\\url
```

Answer (score 0):

Why arn't you putting the configuration information in the web application web.config file?